# Windows 10 UAP - Compiled Data Bindings

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, binding, win-universal-app

According to the Windows 10 SDK kick start videos (http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-preview?prid=ch9courselink) there is a new type of bindings for the Windows 10 universal app platform called "compiled data bindings".

Instead of

```
"{Binding Path=..."
```

the new style is

```
"{x:Bind Path=..."
```

However this only throws in a compiler error that whatever is behind the = is placed does not exist in the context.
Setting

```
"{x:Bind Path=DataContext...."
```

does not work either.
Has anybody managed to get the new bindings to work? Is there ANY documentation on the topic because I don't seem to be able to find anything (not even a sample that you could "reverse engeneer"...

**Update:**
Thanks to Nick's response I can add the following:
Since I usually insert view models after the Page / UserControl is initialized, the Page / UserControl does not seem to notice the updated ViewModel property (even when the Page / UserControl implements and "fires" INotifyPropertyChanged).
Apparently there is a new field in Pages / UserControls called Bindings which can enforce a reset of all compiled data bindings.

So once you change your ViewModel (or another property referenced by x:Bind) you can simply call:

```
Binding.UpdateAll()
```

This way the Page / UserControl reevaluates all compiled data bindings and accepts a "data context switch".

Comment: Does this mean "x:Bind" isn't useful with non Page-based viewmodels such as MvvmLight?

Comment: Answering my own question re MvvmLight.  Just capture the viewmodel in the constructor of the code behind and reference it as part of the bind, as in:  Text="{x:Bind Path=vm.prop, Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: Can't find the Binding.UpdateAll method.

Comment: The problem with the Binding.UpdateAll method is, that it is only created once the page has been compiled. Simply place at least one x:Bind in your XAML and rebuild your application.
The Binding class should then be in the code behind of the page.

Comment: It isn't created for me.

Comment: It should be Bindings.Update(); (instead of Binding.UpdateAll())

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this helps - http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2015/04/26/Compiled-DataBinding-in-Windows-Universal-Applications-(UAP).aspx 
This explains what the context is and how some of the compiled bindings are generated

Comment: Thank you very much. Great blog post!

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add these two links to official documentation since it is available now and the content seems relevant to the subject.

1) [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension)

2) [{x:Bind} and {Binding} feature comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#xbind-and-binding-feature-comparison)